# Search button to activate autocomplete googl maps places (React.js)

Tags: reactjs

I am using AutoComplete button from material/ui for searching Google Maps Places. Everything is working properly so when user clicks on the one offered field in autocomplete it leads him to next page.

My question is: is it possible to add search button to active autocomplete if user clicks on button?

Here is code for autocomplete and I have added button but still nothing happens if someone clicks on it.

```
<div className="search">
        <Autocomplete
          id="google-map-demo"
          key={reset}
          ListboxProps={{ style: { maxHeight: 400, overflow: 'auto',fontSize:'0.7rem' } }}
          getOptionLabel={(option) =>
            typeof option === "string" ? option : option.description
          }
          
          filterOptions={(x) => x}
          options={options}
          onChange={(e, l) => {
            customer.setMyaddress(l.description);
            getMyDestination(l.place_id);
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
             
              {...params}
              className={classes.root} 
              variant="standard"
              fullWidth
              onChange={(e, v) => {
                setInputValue(e.target.value);
              }}
            />
          )}
          renderOption={(option) => {
            const matches =
              option.structured_formatting.main_text_matched_substrings;
            const parts = parse(
              option.structured_formatting.main_text,
              matches.map((match) => [
                match.offset,
                match.offset + match.length,
              ])
            );

            return (
              <Grid container alignItems="center">
                <Grid item>
                  <LocationOnIcon className={classes.icon} />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs>
                  {parts.map((part, index) => (
                    <span
                      key={index}
                      style={{ fontWeight: part.highlight ? 700 : 400 }}
                    >
                      {part.text}
                    </span>
                  ))}

                  <Typography variant="body2" color="red" className={classes.noOptions} >
                    {option.structured_formatting.secondary_text}
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            );
          }}
        />
                <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{position: "absolute",
    right: "0"}}
              onClick={(e, v) => {
                setInputValue(e.target.value);
              }}>Find</button>
</div>
```

Anyone has idea how to fix this so when clicked on button I got same result as clicked on autocomplete field?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use the `open` prop which is in the `Autocomplete` , i've forked the  Autocomplete example from material-ui check it out:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-3n5lw?file=/demo.js